# SQL - Recursive average based on preceding row (AR model)

Tags: sql, recursion, time-series, recursive-query, autoregressive-models

I was wondering how to use either While or Recursion to create an AR(1) model.
In my database I have the following variables in one table (Y is a value):

| Period | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 20171 | Y_0 |
| 20172 | Y_1 |
| 20173 | Y_2 |
| 20174 | Y_3 |
| 20181 | Y_4 |

I'm trying to create a query that will create a new column **AR** which is defined as:

| Period | Value | AR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20171 | Y_0 | Y_0 |
| 20172 | Y_1 | AVG( AR_0 & Y_1) |
| 20173 | Y_2 | AVG( AR_1 & Y_2) |

such as the following:
[Image of desired dataflow from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bd9z.png)

I tried the following:

```
SELECT Period , Values, Values as AR,
INTO #Beginning
FROM table
WHERE Period = (SELECT MIN(PERIOD) FROM table)

SELECT Period , Values, Values as AR,
FROM #Beginning
UNION ALL
SELECT Period , Values, NULL as AR,
FROM table
WHERE Period >(SELECT MIN(PERIOD) FROM table)
```

Which results in a table with the first row in the desired result. However I can't seem to get the rest of the **AR** column, since these are dependent on one another. As of this moment these are null.

Is it possible to use recursion in SQL to create a column, where each row is dependent on one column in the same row, and one column in the preceding row?

Answer (score 0):

You would use window functions.  For instance:

```
select period, value,
       avg(value) over (order by period rows between 1 preceding and current row)
from t;
```

Comment: Does this also include the value column? so that each AR column, has the average of the preceding AR and the current value? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Apeyko . . . I just renamed it to `ar` because I was a little confused.